# Django: 2 active users in a specific url

Tags: django, url, session, cookies, request

I simply don't know how to do it.

I have an html linked with a knew url, with two buttons.
imagine that url is only shared with two persons/users.

each person have to push the button signed their name.

I tried using request, but I couldn't figure out how to know if more than one user is active in that view.

The another point is:

One person reach the url first, how to make an "refresh" in their browser, when the second one appear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to store who's at what view in some model.

```
class UsersInURL(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    url = models.CharField()
    # you'd probably want to use a through table and set up some expiration logic
```

Then remember to modify this model every time a logged in user views a page; middleware sounds perfect for this.

```
class UserTrackerMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
          UsersInURL.users.through.filter(user=request.user).delete()
          users_in_url, created = UsersInURL.objects.get_or_create(url=request.path)
          users_in_url.users.add(request.user)
```

Then to refresh their page, you'd need to set some kind of communication between the server and the browser which pings this model and refreshes if it detects some change.

```
var lastCheckedUsers = undefined;
function checkForNewUsers() {
    $.get('/some-ajaxy-url/', { url: document.URL }, success: function(data) {
         // you'd have to set up a view that returns active users @ url
         if (lastCheckedUsers != data.users && lastCheckedUsers != undefined) {
            window.location.href = window.location.href; 
         };
        lastCheckedUsers = data.users;  // store last state; refresh if modified. 
    })
};
setInterval(checkForNewUsers, 1000);
```

I'm sure that should get some ideas flowing.